# Firing a trigger from 2 different jQuery Codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, click, fancybox

I'm trying to use FancyBox Script combined with a custom slideshow, but i cant make it work.

Here's me page:
http://www.edital.co.il/?page_id=37 (if the link is not working, just wait and reload again)

As you can see (line 53), i made the fancybox popup right after it loads just for test that the fancybox is working.

The problem starts inside the script 'http://www.edital.co.il/wp-content/themes/ediTal/library/js/libs/zoom-showcase.js?ver=3.4.2' (script loaded at line 145)
inside the file, at line 57: $this.trigger('click');

```
function gotoURL(event) {
    var $this = $(this); // the <li> that has the youtube href attribute.
    // the <li> has class="fancybox-youtube", so it should work:
    $this.trigger('click'); // should trigger the <li>, but its not! (the problem)
}
```

the trigger is set at line 67 on the html file by fancybox:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    /* Fancybox code start... */
    var fb_timeout = null;
    var fb_opts = { 'overlayShow' : true, 'centerOnScroll' : true, 'showCloseButton' : true, 'showNavArrows' : true, 'onCleanup' : function() { if(fb_timeout) { window.clearTimeout(fb_timeout); fb_timeout = null; } } };
    $('[href*="youtube.com/"]:not(.nofancybox)').addClass('fancybox-youtube');
    $('[href*="youtu.be/"]:not(.nofancybox)').addClass('fancybox-youtube');
    $('.fancybox-youtube').fancybox( $.extend({}, fb_opts, { 'type' : 'iframe', 'width' : 640, 'height' : 390, 'padding' : 0, 'autoScale' : false, 'titleShow' : false, 'titlePosition' : 'float', 'titleFromAlt' : true, 'onStart' : function(selectedArray, selectedIndex, selectedOpts) { selectedOpts.href = selectedArray[selectedIndex].href.replace(new RegExp('youtu.be', 'i'), 'www.youtube.com/embed').replace(new RegExp('watch\\?v=([a-z0-9\_\-]+)(&|\\?)?(.*)', 'i'), 'embed/$1?version=3&$3') } }) );
    /* Fancybox code end... */

    /* Thats working, but gotoURL() does not. */ 
    $('a[class=fancybox-youtube]').filter(':first').trigger('click'); 
});
```

Basically whats going on:
Fancybox is adding a "fancybox-youtube" class to any tag with href=youtube...

My guess- they both have a different $ and that's why they don't work together. I don't know if that's what causing the problem though.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide some code here in your question so that your question can stand on it's own after your page is fixed.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that illustrates your problem?

Comment: That link appears to be dead.

Comment: Yeah the hosting is really bad... just refresh it again, it should work. about a minimal-example, its not possible for me atm, but i can provide some more information if somthing is not clear enough.